# Why post__not_in is ignored?

Tags: wp-query, pages

I'm using the following snippet below, but the 'post__not_in' is not excluding the page id's defined in the variable. I also tried the 'exclude', both of them are not working. How to fix this?

```
$exclude_ids = array(294,278,6758,9582,9674,8638,8585,7359);
$args = array(
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'post__in'       => $ids,
            'post__not_in'   => $exclude_ids,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
            'order'          => 'ASC'
    );

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

"post__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify post NOT to retrieve. **If this is used in the same query as post__in, it will be ignored.**"

Try to make an array of the post id's you do want to display, OR an array of the post id's you want to exclude instead of trying to do both.

Edit: If you want to exclude a particular set of pages, with your current code, you would simply remove the conflicting 'post__in' parameter you have in your `$args`, and your query should work after:

```
$exclude_ids = array(294,278,6758,9582,9674,8638,8585,7359);
$args = array(
        'paged'          => $paged,
        /***** 'post__in'       => $ids, ***** Remove this line *****/
        'post__not_in'   => $exclude_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
        'order'          => 'ASC'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: how to do this? can you please help me with this

Comment: If you tell me more about what you want to accomplish(i.e. what is this specific list of pages?), I may be able to suggest how to get your wanted id's into an array.

Comment: I just want to exclude certain pages in the list. Here's my full code http://jsfiddle.net/mYrMz/20/

Comment: Please see updated Edit in my answer.